# Import Plugin Error

Tags: import, plugin-import

Getting error

```
"Craft\Import_HistoryRecord and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "type".
```

`Import_HistoryRecord` is one of the Plugin Files in the "records" folder.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Import_HistoryRecord extends BaseRecord
{

    public function getTableName()
    {
        return 'import_history';
    }

    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'type'     => AttributeType::String,
            'file'     => AttributeType::Name,
            'rows'     => AttributeType::Number,
            'behavior' => array(AttributeType::Enum, 'values' => array(ImportModel::BehaviorAppend, ImportModel::BehaviorReplace, ImportModel::BehaviorDelete)),
            'status'   => array(AttributeType::Enum, 'values' => array(ImportModel::StatusStarted, ImportModel::StatusFinished, ImportModel::StatusReverted))
        );
    }

    public function defineRelations()
    {
        return array(
            'user' => array(static::BELONGS_TO, 'UserRecord',       'onDelete' => static::CASCADE, 'required' => false),
            'log'  => array(static::HAS_MANY,   'Import_LogRecord', 'logId')
        );
    }

}
```

It worked a month ago when I used it, don't think I am doing anything differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer recently added multiple types of import - Entry, User and Category.

Your import history in the database saved prior to this recent update - I think the db table is called craft_import_history or similar - doesn't have a type saved against so an error is being thrown.

Edit the rows in that table directly and either delete them or edit the type column and add the correct value.